# Go program going into partial deadlock after running a few hours or even days. Threads in wait_chain and increasing amounts of memory

Tags: go, tcp, concurrency, udp, deadlock

The program runs in 4 machines, two Win7 and two Win10, for hours or even days, until task manager reports some threads in the wait chain and large amounts of memory being used. The program doesn't crash and no error messages are displayed in the command window. Some of the goroutines continue running but others are not responsive. I commented out all log.Print, out of desperation, but no difference.
The program communicates on port 30123 with another program running in the 4 machines. It has a TCP server on 30133 and a UDP server on 30143 for communication with the same program on the other three machines.

I wrote the original version about three years ago and then forgot about it until recently when I noticed some partially frozen programs. I didn't remember anymore what I had done and had almost forgotten GO completely, so I made some unsuccessful modifications in go 1.15. As this didn't solve the problem I recompiled it with 1.14.13, after removing Ticker.Reset in one of the threads.

My assumption is that, doing to my rusted programming ability and GO inexperience, I am doing something really stupid that someone experienced in GO will spot immediately.

Parts of the code

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

// For goroutine  debugging only
var (
    loggersTime,
    userTime,
    tCPTime,
    uDPTime,
    processInputTime,
    workerTime time.Time
    loggersCount,
    userCount,
    tCPCount,
    uDPCount,
    advertiseCount,
    serveCount,
    workerCount int
    dbgMutex sync.Mutex
)

type stationIP struct {
    ip   string
    port string
}

type timeCount struct {
    tw     time.Time
    temail time.Time
    count  int
}

var stationTimeCount = map[string]timeCount{}
var stationMutex sync.RWMutex
var stationsAddr map[string]stationIP

const nODATA = "Nothing"

// const fOLDERNAME = "c:\\loggers\\"
const cHECKINTER = 120 * time.Second
const wRITEINTER = 10 * time.Minute

// const cHECKINTER = 10*time.Second
// const wRITEINTER = 2*time.Minute
const eEMAILINTER = 2 * time.Hour

var emails = ...

// const emails = ...
var emailSender = ...

// States of handshaking between checkers
const (
    Stopped = iota
    Worker
    Backup
    NoEmail
)

var stateStrList = [...]string{Stopped: "Stopped", Backup: "Backup", Worker: "Worker", NoEmail: "NoEmail"}

var checkState = Stopped
var setWorkerChan chan string
var checkMutex sync.Mutex

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.LstdFlags | log.Lshortfile)
    fileWrite("\r\nstarted:" + time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05") + "\r\n")
    getStationInfo("emsys_check.cfg")
    for key, value := range stationsAddr {
        log.Printf("%s:\t%s, %s\r\n", key, value.ip, value.port)
    }
    gasmail.AddEmail(emails)
    gasmail.PrintEmail()
    setWorkerChan = make(chan string)
    wg.Add(1)
    go handleLoggers()
    go handleUser()
    go handleTCP()
    go handleUDP()
    go handleWorker()

    wg.Wait()
    // log.Println("main leaving")
    fileWrite("stopped:" + time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05") + "\r\n")
}

func readLines(filePath string) ([]string, error) {
    // // log.Println(filePath)
    f, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    var lines []string
    var str string
    scanner := bufio.NewReader(f)
    for err == nil {
        str, err = scanner.ReadString('\n')
        str = strings.TrimRight(str, "\f\r\n")
        if str == "" {
            continue
        }
        lines = append(lines, str)
    }
    return lines, nil
}

var fmutex sync.Mutex

// fileWrite writes text to a monthly file
// uses a mutex to access file
func fileWrite(text string) {
    var err error
    var f *os.File
    fmutex.Lock()
    defer fmutex.Unlock()

    fn := "emsys" + time.Now().Format("2006-01") + ".log"
    if fileExists(fn) {
        f, err = os.OpenFile(fn, os.O_RDWR|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
        // // log.Printf("%s exists\n", fn)
    } else {
        // // log.Printf("%s doesn't exist\n", fn)
        f, err = os.Create(fn)
    }
    if err != nil {
        // log.Printf("Error opening %s\r\n", fn)
        return
    }
    f.Write([]byte(text))
    f.Close()
}

//
func readLogger(ipaddr string) (string, error) {
    var newData [1024]byte
    msg := "ok"

    //// log.Println("Entered: readLogger")
    conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", ipaddr, 5*time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        // log.Println(err.Error())
        fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("conn:%v readLogger DialTimeout: %s\r\n", conn, err.Error()))
        return nODATA, err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    if err = conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second)); err != nil {
        // // log.Println(err.Error())
        fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("readLogger SetWriteDeadline: %s\r\n", err.Error()))
    }
    _, err = conn.Write([]byte(msg))
    if err != nil {
        // log.Println(err.Error())
        fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("readLogger Write: %s\r\n", err.Error()))
        return nODATA, err
    }
    if err = conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(5 * time.Second)); err != nil {
        // log.Println(err.Error())
        fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("readLogger SetReadDeadline: %s\r\n", err.Error()))
    }
    n, err := conn.Read(newData[0:])
    if err != nil {
        // // log.Println(err.Error())
        fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("readLogger Read: %s\r\n", err.Error()))
        return nODATA, err
    }
    //// log.Println("Leaving: readLogger"+string(newData[0:n]))
    return strings.TrimRight(string(newData[0:n]), "\r\n"), nil
}

func getTimeCount(station string) timeCount {
    stationMutex.RLock()
    defer stationMutex.RUnlock()
    return stationTimeCount[station]
}

func setTimeCount(station string, tc timeCount) {
    stationMutex.Lock()
    defer stationMutex.Unlock()
    stationTimeCount[station] = tc
}

func getStationIP(station string) string {
    stationMutex.RLock()
    defer stationMutex.RUnlock()
    return stationsAddr[station].ip
}

func setStationIP(station, ip string) {
    stationMutex.Lock()
    defer stationMutex.Unlock()
    oldst := stationsAddr[station]
    oldst.ip = ip
    stationsAddr[station] = oldst
}

func getStationPort(station string) string {
    stationMutex.RLock()
    defer stationMutex.RUnlock()
    return stationsAddr[station].port
}

func setStationPort(station, port string) {
    stationMutex.Lock()
    defer stationMutex.Unlock()
    oldst := stationsAddr[station]
    oldst.port = port
    stationsAddr[station] = oldst
}

// checkStation checks the status of the station logger
func checkStation(station string) {
    if getStationIP(station)[0] == '0' {
        return
    }
    incRunGo()
    defer decRunGo()

    oldTimeCount := getTimeCount(station)
    host, _ := os.Hostname()

    logChange := func(err error, okNew bool, newData string) {
        // log on change of state or every WRITEINTER
        tNew := time.Now()
        if (okNew && oldTimeCount.count > 0) || (!okNew && oldTimeCount.count == 1) || (tNew.Sub(oldTimeCount.tw) > wRITEINTER) {
            errmsg := ":" + host
            if err != nil {
                errmsg += ":" + err.Error()
            }
            tstr := tNew.Format("2006_01_02 15:04:05") + ": "
            text := fmt.Sprintf("logChange %s:%s\r\n", station, newData+errmsg)
            // // log.Print(text)
            fileWrite(tstr + text)
            oldTimeCount.tw = tNew
        }
    }

    checkEmailRequired := func(okNew bool) {
        // at the third consecutive unsuccessful attempt notify through email if worker
        // if >= 3 unsuccessful before and new attempt successful notify through email if worker
        tNew := time.Now()
        if getCheckState() == Worker &&
            ((okNew && oldTimeCount.count >= 3) ||
                (!okNew && oldTimeCount.count == 3) ||
                (tNew.Sub(oldTimeCount.temail) > eEMAILINTER)) {
            tstr := tNew.Format("2006_01_02 15:04:05") + ": "
            text := " "
            if okNew {
                text += station + " email running"
            } else {
                text += station + " email down"
            }
            errmsg := ":" + host
            msgs := append([]string{tstr + text}, str2List(errmsg[1:], 60)...)
            // // log.Println(text)
            fileWrite(tstr + text)
            // // log.Println("worker emailing")
            if !gasmail.Sendmaillisthydro(emailSender, msgs) {
                setCheckState(NoEmail)
                text := "worker to noemail\r\n"
                // log.Print(text)
                fileWrite(tstr + text)
            } else {
                oldTimeCount.temail = tNew
            }
        }
    }

    newData, err := readLogger(getStationIP(station) + ":" + getStationPort(station))
    okNew := newData != nODATA
    if !okNew {
        oldTimeCount.count++
    }

    logChange(err, okNew, newData)
    checkEmailRequired(okNew)

    tNew := time.Now()
    if getCheckState() != Worker {
        oldTimeCount.temail = tNew
    }
    if okNew {
        oldTimeCount.temail = tNew
        oldTimeCount.count = 0 // reset the counter when a success
    }
    setTimeCount(station, oldTimeCount)
}

var running = true
var runMutex sync.Mutex

func isRunning() bool {
    runMutex.Lock()
    defer runMutex.Unlock()
    return running
}

// handleLoggers checks the stations loggers status
func handleLoggers() {
    t1 := time.Now().Add(-1 * time.Hour)

    for key := range stationsAddr {
        setTimeCount(key, timeCount{tw: t1, temail: t1, count: 0})
    }

    log.Println("handleLoggers entering")
    incRunGo()
    defer decRunGo()
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()
    tickerCheck := time.NewTicker(cHECKINTER)
    tickerSleep := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)

    for isRunning() {
        dbgMutex.Lock()
        loggersCount++
        dbgMutex.Unlock()

        select {
        case <-tickerCheck.C:
            for key := range stationsAddr {
                go checkStation(key)
            }
        case <-tickerSleep.C:
            dbgMutex.Lock()
            loggersTime = time.Now()
            dbgMutex.Unlock()
        }
        dbgMutex.Lock()
        if loggersCount > 12 {
            loggersCount = 0
        }
        dbgMutex.Unlock()
    }
    tickerSleep.Stop()
    tickerCheck.Stop()
    log.Println("handleLoggers leaving")
}

var help = []string{"quit", "ip[LS|LM|KT|GR|...]: ip",
    "port[LS|LM|KT|GR|...]: port", "add:Email", "rem:Email",
    "check"}

func showhelp() {
    // log.Printf("\r\n%q: %d\r\n", help, getCheckState())
}

// processInput processes the data received from the User or from TCP
func processInput(text string) string {
    dbgMutex.Lock()
    processInputTime = time.Now()
    dbgMutex.Unlock()

    ipre, _ := regexp.Compile("^\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}$")
    portre, _ := regexp.Compile("^\\d{1,5}$")

    ret := ""
    textLoc := strings.ToLower(strings.TrimSpace(text)) + "             " // make sure text is long enough
    if textLoc[:4] == "quit" {
        ret = "quit"
    } else if textLoc[:5] == "debug" {
        ret = getLogThreads()
    } else if textLoc[:2] == "ip" {
        stname := strings.ToUpper(textLoc[2:4])
        ip := strings.Trim(textLoc[4:], ": ")
        if ipre.Match([]byte(ip)) {
            setStationIP(stname, ip)
        }
        ret = fmt.Sprintf("ipaddr%s: %s", stname, getStationIP(stname))
    } else if textLoc[:4] == "port" {
        stname := strings.ToUpper(textLoc[4:6])
        port := strings.Trim(textLoc[6:], ": ")
        if portre.Match([]byte(port)) {
            setStationPort(stname, port)
        }
        ret = fmt.Sprintf("port%s: %s", stname, getStationPort(stname))
    } else if textLoc[:3] == "add" {
        gasmail.AddEmail(strings.Trim(text[3:], ": "))
        ret = gasmail.GetEmail()
    } else if textLoc[:3] == "rem" {
        gasmail.RemEmail(strings.Trim(textLoc[3:], ": "))
        ret = gasmail.GetEmail()
    } else if textLoc[:5] == "check" {
        ret = fmt.Sprintf("check: %s", getCheckStateStr())
    } else if textLoc[:6] == "worker" {
        ret = strings.TrimRight(textLoc, " ")
    } else {
        ret = fmt.Sprintf("%q: %s", help, getCheckStateStr())
    }
    return ret
}

var runGo = 1 // for main

// getLogThreads gathers some goroutines information
func getLogThreads() string {
    dbgMutex.Lock()
    defer dbgMutex.Unlock()
    str := fmt.Sprintf("%s: run:%2d runi:%2d User:%s:[%2d] TCP:%s:[%2d:serve:%2d] UDP:%s:[%2d] Worker:%s:[%2d:adv:%2d] Loggers:%s:[%2d] Input:%s\r\n",
        getCheckStateStr(),
        runtime.NumGoroutine(),
        runGo,
        userTime.Format("15:04:05"), userCount,
        tCPTime.Format("15:04:05"), tCPCount, serveCount,
        uDPTime.Format("15:04:05"), uDPCount,
        workerTime.Format("15:04:05"), workerCount, advertiseCount,
        loggersTime.Format("15:04:05"), loggersCount,
        processInputTime.Format("15:04:05"))
    return str
}

func logThreads() string {
    str := getLogThreads()
    dbgFileWrite(str)
    // log.Printf("\r\n" + str)
    return str
}

// accepts user commands and signals stop
// to other goroutines
func handleUser() {
    defer wg.Done()

    log.Println("handleUser entering")
    incRunGo()
    defer decRunGo()
    showhelp()
    told := time.Now()
    tickerSleep := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)

    ch := make(chan string)
    go func(ch chan string) {
        incRunGo()
        defer decRunGo()
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        for {
            s, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
            ch <- s
            if len(s) >= 4 && s[:4] == "quit" {
                break
            }
        }
    }(ch)

    actionStr := ""
    for isRunning() {
        dbgMutex.Lock()
        userCount++
        dbgMutex.Unlock()

        select {
        case text, _ := <-ch:
            actionStr = processInput(text)
            // log.Println(actionStr)
            fileWrite(time.Now().Format("15:04:05") + actionStr + "\r\n")
            if actionStr == "quit" {
                runMutex.Lock()
                running = false
                runMutex.Unlock()
            }
        case <-tickerSleep.C:
            dbgMutex.Lock()
            userTime = time.Now()
            dbgMutex.Unlock()
            if userTime.Sub(told) > 10*time.Minute {
                told = userTime
                logThreads()
            }
        }
        dbgMutex.Lock()
        if userCount > 12 {
            userCount = 0
        }
        dbgMutex.Unlock()
    }
    close(ch)
    tickerSleep.Stop()
    log.Println("handleUser leaving")
}

// process information to answer commands received
func handleTCP() {
    var conn net.Conn
    var err error

    log.Println("handleTCP entering")
    incRunGo()
    defer decRunGo()
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()

    service := ":30133"
    val, err := strconv.Atoi(getStationPort("LS"))
    if err == nil {
        service = ":" + strconv.Itoa(val+10)
    }
    tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", service)
    checkError(err)
    // log.Printf("service on %v\r\n", tcpAddr)

    listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", tcpAddr)
    checkError(err)
    defer listener.Close()

    t1 := time.Now()
    tdiff := time.Second
    for isRunning() {
        dbgMutex.Lock()
        tCPCount++
        tCPTime = time.Now()
        dbgMutex.Unlock()
        t1 = time.Now()

        if err = listener.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(5 * time.Second)); err != nil {
            // log.Printf("handleTCP SetDeadline: %s\r\n", err.Error())
            fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("handleTCP SetDeadline: %s\r\n", err.Error()))
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        } else {
            conn, err = listener.Accept()
            if err == nil {
                go serveClient(conn)
            }
        }

        tdiff = time.Now().Sub(t1)
        if tdiff < 5*time.Second && getCheckState() == Worker {
            // log.Printf("Accept time: %q\r\n", tdiff)
            fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("handleTCP Accept time: %q\r\n", tdiff))
        }
        dbgMutex.Lock()
        if tCPCount > 12 {
            tCPCount = 0
        }
        dbgMutex.Unlock()
    }
    log.Println("handleTCP leaving")
}

const uDPport = ":30143"

// process information from other partners to define who is the Worker
// if the received message starts with "worker", sends the ip address of the sender
// plus the result of processInput, through setWorkerChan to be read by handleWorker
// received: "worker: 142.16.214.197"
// sent to setWorkerChan: "142.16.214.197:58695:worker: 142.16.214.197"
func handleUDP() {
    var err error

    log.Println("handleUDP entering")
    incRunGo()
    defer decRunGo()
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()

    service := uDPport
    val, err := strconv.Atoi(getStationPort("LS"))
    if err == nil {
        service = ":" + strconv.Itoa(val+20)
    }
    udpAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", service)
    checkError(err)
    // log.Printf("UDP service on %v\r\n", udpAddr)

    listener, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", udpAddr)
    checkError(err)
    defer listener.Close()

    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    actionStr := ""
    for isRunning() {
        dbgMutex.Lock()
        uDPCount++
        uDPTime = time.Now()
        dbgMutex.Unlock()

        if err = listener.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(5 * time.Second)); err != nil {
            // log.Printf("handleUDP SetDeadline: %s\r\n", err.Error())
            fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("handleUDP SetDeadline: %s\r\n", err.Error()))
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
        } else {
            n, addr, err := listener.ReadFromUDP(buf)
            if err == nil {
                actionStr = processInput(string(buf[0:n]))
                if len(actionStr) >= 6 && actionStr[:6] == "worker" { // there is a "worker" partner
                    setWorkerChan <- addr.String() + ":" + actionStr
                }
            }
        }
        dbgMutex.Lock()
        if uDPCount > 12 {
            uDPCount = 0
        }
        dbgMutex.Unlock()
    }
    log.Println("handleUDP leaving")
}

func incRunGo() {
    dbgMutex.Lock()
    runGo++
    dbgMutex.Unlock()
}

func decRunGo() {
    dbgMutex.Lock()
    runGo--
    dbgMutex.Unlock()
}

func serveClient(conn net.Conn) {
    var data [512]byte

    dbgMutex.Lock()
    serveCount++
    dbgMutex.Unlock()

    incRunGo()
    defer decRunGo()
    defer conn.Close()
    if err := conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second)); err != nil {
        // log.Println(err.Error())
        fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("serveClient SetReadDeadline: %s\r\n", err.Error()))
    }
    // read upto 512 bytes
    n, err := conn.Read(data[0:])
    if err != nil {
        // log.Println(err.Error())
        fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("serveClient Read: %s\r\n", err.Error()))
    }
    actionStr := processInput(string(data[0:n]))
    if len(actionStr) >= 6 && actionStr[:6] == "worker" { // there is a "worker" partner
        setWorkerChan <- conn.RemoteAddr().String() + ":" + actionStr
    }
    if err := conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second)); err != nil {
        // log.Println(err.Error())
        fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("serveClient SetWriteDeadline: %s\r\n", err.Error()))
    }
    // write the response
    if _, err := conn.Write([]byte(actionStr)); err != nil {
        // log.Println(err.Error())
        fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("serveClient Write: %s\r\n", err.Error()))
    }
    dbgMutex.Lock()
    if serveCount > 12 {
        serveCount = 0
    }
    dbgMutex.Unlock()
}

func getCheckState() int {
    checkMutex.Lock()
    defer checkMutex.Unlock()
    return checkState
}

func getCheckStateStr() string {
    checkMutex.Lock()
    defer checkMutex.Unlock()
    return stateStrList[checkState]
}
func setCheckState(newstate int) {
    checkMutex.Lock()
    defer checkMutex.Unlock()
    checkState = newstate
}

func handleWorker() {
    var WorkerCnt int
    var sender string
    tickerSleep := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)

    log.Println("handleWorker entering")
    incRunGo()
    defer decRunGo()
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()
    myip := fmt.Sprintf("%s", getOutboundIP())

    advertise := func(msg string) {
        var conn net.Conn
        var err error

        incRunGo()
        defer decRunGo()
        service := uDPport
        val, err := strconv.Atoi(getStationPort("LS"))
        if err == nil {
            service = ":" + strconv.Itoa(val+20)
        }
        // service = ":30153" // For testing ONLY!
        for _, v := range stationsAddr {
            if v.ip[0] == '0' || v.ip == myip {
                continue
            }

            dbgMutex.Lock()
            advertiseCount++
            dbgMutex.Unlock()
            conn, err = net.DialTimeout("udp", v.ip+service, 10*time.Second)
            if err != nil {
                // log.Println(err.Error())
                fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("conn: %v advertise DialTimeout: %s\r\n", conn, err.Error()))
                continue
            }
            if err = conn.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second)); err != nil {
                // log.Println(err.Error())
                fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("advertise SetWriteDeadline: %s\r\n", err.Error()))
            }
            _, err = conn.Write([]byte(msg))
            if err != nil {
                // log.Println(err.Error())
                fileWrite(fmt.Sprintf("advertise Write: %s\r\n", err.Error()))
            }
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            conn.Close()
            dbgMutex.Lock()
            if advertiseCount > 12 {
                advertiseCount = 0
            }
            dbgMutex.Unlock()
        }
    }

    processChanReceived := func(state int, senderText string) {
        text := ""
        tstr := time.Now().Format("15:04:05") + ": "
        if state == Backup {
            text = fmt.Sprintf("%s: backup counter %d\r\n", senderText, WorkerCnt)
            WorkerCnt = 0
        } else if state == Worker {
            setCheckState(Backup) // some other node also became a Worker, so move to Backup
            text = fmt.Sprintf("worker to backup: %s [%d]\r\n", senderText, WorkerCnt)
            fileWrite(tstr + text)
            WorkerCnt = 0
        } else {
            text = fmt.Sprintf("sender %s: noemail counter %d\r\n", senderText, WorkerCnt)
            fileWrite(tstr + text)
        }
        // log.Print(text)
    }

    processIdle := func(state int) {
        text := ""
        tstr := time.Now().Format("15:04:05") + ": "

        if state == Backup {
            WorkerCnt++
            if WorkerCnt >= 30 {
                go advertise("worker: " + myip)
                setCheckState(Worker)
                // become Worker because timeout reached without receiving Worker notification
                text = fmt.Sprintf("backup to worker counter: %d\r\n", WorkerCnt)
                fileWrite(tstr + text)
                WorkerCnt = 0
            }
        } else if state == Worker {
            WorkerCnt++
            if WorkerCnt == 5 {
                text = "advertise: worker: " + myip + "\r\n"
                go advertise("worker: " + myip)
                WorkerCnt = 0
            }
        } else { // NoEmail
            WorkerCnt++
            if WorkerCnt > 400 {
                setCheckState(Backup)
                text = fmt.Sprintf("noemail to backup [%d]\r\n", WorkerCnt)
                fileWrite(tstr + text)
                WorkerCnt = 0
            }
        }
        if len(text) > 0 {
            // log.Print(text)
        }
    }

    setCheckState(Backup)
    advertise("online: " + myip)
    // log.Printf("%s\r\n", getCheckStateStr())

    for isRunning() {
        dbgMutex.Lock()
        workerCount++
        workerTime = time.Now()
        dbgMutex.Unlock()

        select {
        case sender = <-setWorkerChan:
            processChanReceived(getCheckState(), sender)
        case <-tickerSleep.C:
            processIdle(getCheckState())
        }

        dbgMutex.Lock()
        if workerCount > 12 {
            workerCount = 0
        }
        dbgMutex.Unlock()
    }
    tickerSleep.Stop()
    log.Println("handleWorker leaving")
}
```

Comment: begin by building and running your program with the race detector enabled. Make use of expvar to atomically increment a variable rather than the mutex+global+log, you will be able to browse them in a web interface. Enable the web interface to profile your program especially the various stack dumps that should give you more details as to what is blocked see https://rafallorenz.com/go/go-profiling-http-service-with-pprof-and-expvar/ for some introduction. Please consider that it is unlikely that someone will fully reverse enginner your program, and its input, to debug it.

Comment: program has been compiled with -race option but never reported anything. By the way, the problems started occurring when we migrated two of the machines from win7 to win10. It worked without any noticeable problems for 3 years in all 4 win7 machines. Thanks for your help mh-cbon.

Comment: Program ran well for more than a week in linux mint and in old 2-core win7. After much sweating, I found out that in new machines, with 4 or more processors, setting affinity to 1 in Task Manager solves the problem. Even though my program as shown needs some cleaning (some of the dirt was introduced to debug it), its concurrency has no bugs, so this looks like a GO GC or Scheduler issue in Win10. Anyway, the set affinity works and I have my problem solved.

Comment: do you cross compile ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217320/multi-threading-performance-much-worse-on-windows-10-than-linux

Comment: No cross compile

Comment: runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2) works as well as set affinity to 2 cores. 
I created another program that just uses http.HandleFunc("/view/", viewHandler) without any explicit goroutines and it also hangs in Win10, showing threads in the WAIT_CHAIN, but never did during 3 years in old win7.
The concurrency model of golang is nice, but probably has some issues in Win10, less used than linux or Mac for golang development.